# Postgresql - Using subqueries with alter sequence expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sequence, alter

Is it possible to use subqueries within alter expressions in PostgreSQL?

I want to alter a sequence value based on a primary key column value.

I tried using the following expression, but it wouldn't execute.

```
alter sequence public.sequenceX restart with (select max(table_id)+1 from table)
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it like that but you should be able to use the setval function direction which is what the alter does.

```
select setval('sequenceX', (select max(table_id)+1 from table), false)
```

The false will make it return the next sequence number as exactly what is given.

Comment: `select setval('sequenceX', (select max(table_id) from table))` will accomplish the same thing, since the last parameter, "is_called", defaults to true, but also correctly handles the case where you might have created that sequence with an INCREMENT BY value other than 1.

Comment: do i need a from table at the end of the whole statement? "missing from clause"

Answer (score 8):

In addition if you have mixed case object names and you're getting an error like this:

```
ERROR: relation "public.mytable_id_seq" does not exist
```

... the following version using regclass should be useful:

```
select setval('"public"."MyTable_Id_seq"'::regclass, (select MAX("Id") FROM "public"."MyTable"))
```

Comment: took me a bit to notice the single quotes around the double quotes!

Comment: you absolute HERO. I sunk about 4 hrs into this problem and this fixed it. Thanks!