# Postgresql - SQL query to list all sequences in database

Tags: postgresql, sequence, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, catalog

I would like to select all sequences in the database, get the schema of sequence, dependent table, the schema of a table, dependent column.

I've tried the following query:

```
  SELECT 
    ns.nspname AS sequence_schema_name, 
    s.relname AS sequence_name, 
    t_ns.nspname AS table_schema_name, 
    t.relname AS table_name, 
    a.attname AS column_name,
    s.oid,
    s.relnamespace,
    d.*,
    a.*
  FROM pg_class s
  JOIN pg_namespace ns 
  ON ns.oid = s.relnamespace
  left JOIN pg_depend d --
  ON d.objid = s.oid --TO FIX???
    AND d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass --TO FIX???
    AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass --TO FIX???
  left JOIN pg_class t 
  ON t.oid = d.refobjid --TO FIX???
  left JOIN pg_attribute a 
  ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid 
     AND a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
  left JOIN pg_namespace t_ns 
  ON t.relnamespace = t_ns.oid
  WHERE s.relkind = 'S' 
;
```

Unfortunately, this query does not work at 100%. The query filter some sequences.

I need it for further processing (after data restore on different ENV, I need to find max column-value  and set sequence to MAX+1).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: "*I need to find max column-value and set sequence to MAX+1*" - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059947)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should to work:

```
create table foo(id serial, v integer);
create table boo(id_boo serial, v integer);
create sequence omega;
create table bubu(id integer default nextval('omega'), v integer);

select sn.nspname as seq_schema,
       s.relname as seqname,
       st.nspname as tableschema,
       t.relname as tablename,
       at.attname as columname
  from pg_class s
  join pg_namespace sn on sn.oid = s.relnamespace
  join pg_depend d on d.refobjid = s.oid 
  join pg_attrdef a on d.objid = a.oid
  join pg_attribute at on at.attrelid = a.adrelid and at.attnum = a.adnum
  join pg_class t on t.oid = a.adrelid
  join pg_namespace st on st.oid = t.relnamespace
 where s.relkind = 'S'
   and d.classid = 'pg_attrdef'::regclass
   and d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass;
┌────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ seq_schema │    seqname     │ tableschema │ tablename │ columname │
╞════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ public     │ foo_id_seq     │ public      │ foo       │ id        │
│ public     │ boo_id_boo_seq │ public      │ boo       │ id_boo    │
│ public     │ omega          │ public      │ bubu      │ id        │
└────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
(3 rows)
```

For calling sequence related functions you can use `s.oid` column. For this case, it is sequence unique oid identifier. You need cast it to `regclass`.

A script for you request can looks like:

```
do $$
declare
  r record;
  max_val bigint;
begin
  for r in
    select s.oid as seqoid,
           at.attname as colname,
           a.adrelid as reloid
      from pg_class s
      join pg_namespace sn on sn.oid = s.relnamespace
      join pg_depend d on d.refobjid = s.oid 
      join pg_attrdef a on d.objid = a.oid
      join pg_attribute at on at.attrelid = a.adrelid and at.attnum = a.adnum
     where s.relkind = 'S'
       and d.classid = 'pg_attrdef'::regclass 
       and d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  loop
    -- probably lock here can be safer, in safe (single user) maintainance mode
    -- it is not necessary
    execute format('lock table %s in exclusive mode', r.reloid::regclass);

    -- expect usual one sequnce per table
    execute format('select COALESCE(max(%I),0) from %s', r.colname, r.reloid::regclass)
       into max_val;

    -- set sequence
    perform setval(r.seqoid, max_val + 1);
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

Note: Using `%s` for table name or sequence name in `format` function is safe, because the cast from `Oid` type to `regclass` type generate safe string (schema is used when it is necessary every time, escaping is used when it is needed every time).

Comment: oh great. Thank you for the explanation and this script is working very well.

Comment: PostgreSQL provides a view to get details on all sequences, cf https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-sequences.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-sequences.html