# Reset Postgres Sequence to Next Id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, data-migration

**What Happened?**

We migrated from MySQL to Postgres and had Laravel re-run it's migrations with the psql driver instead of mysql. Worked great - it setup the database just fine. Since we are moving from Laravel to Rails, we created rails migrations to rename fields to be more 'rails-like' as well as to import the db data(not the structure) into postgres. We have run into a lot of issues from this, but most importantly sequences are jacked for auto increments now. They are trying to start from 1.

**What Can I Not Figure Out?**

I can manually reset all of them using something like `SELECT pg_catalog.setval('availabilities_id_seq', 700, false);` but that isn't very helpful as we do this on multiple environments with so many tables.  ***Is there a way you can think of to find the last autoincrement id and then set the sequence from that?***

In case you're curious, here is the Rails migration to move the data incase anyone has tips on how we did this wrong (my_models being the array of tables):

```
my_models.each do |m|
  puts m
  "Mysql#{m}".constantize.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |old_model|
    new_model = m.constantize.new
    new_model.attributes = old_model.attributes
    new_model.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following discussions:

1. [Postgresql - Using subqueries with alter sequence expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022559/postgresql-using-subqueries-with-alter-sequence-expressions)
2. [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

PostgreSQL wiki also have a possible solution to you case: [Fixing Sequences](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences).