# Using result of select inside alter table statement in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, auto-increment

I have a postgres table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE public.Table_1
(
  id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 
  START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 )
)
```

Due to data migration, the id column is messed up and the value for id that is being generated on INSERT is not unique. Hence, I need to reset the id column as below

```
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 From Table_1;
ALTER TABLE Table_1 ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 935074;
```

Right now I run the first query to get the Max(id) + 1 value and then I need to substitute it in the ALTER query.
Is there a way to store the result of SELECT and just use the variable inside ALTER statement?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Why do you want to set the value of an `id` column?  Can you better describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So, I am migrating data into postgres and Id column is defined as an identity which is always generated. After the migration, Id column got messed up and it is not auto-generating unique values. So, as a fix I am trying to restart the sequence using the above 2 queries and I have to do this for about 20 tables.

Comment: If I understand your problem, you are trying to use a sub-query as part of an ALTER statement, which I don't believe is possible. However if the ID you are trying to adjust is a postgres sequence, you should be able to change the value. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022559/postgresql-using-subqueries-with-alter-sequence-expressions

Comment: Thanks. That was useful. id field was defined as:
id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 )
So, I had to first get the sequence name using pg_get_serial_sequence function and then set the value using:
select setval('table_1_id_seq', (select max(id)+1 from notificationrequest), false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('Table_1', 'id'), coalesce(max(id),0) + 1, false) 
from Table_1;
```

Rationale:

- `pg_get_serial_sequence()` returns the name of the sequence for the given table and column
- `set_val()` can be used to reset the sequence
- this can be wrapped in a `select` that gives you the current maximum value of `id` in the table (or 1 if the table is empty)